# What is the default behavior for instancing service objects in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I've been preparing for MS 70-513 exam and with the Self-paced training kit content cd there are some practice tests.

The following is one question of those tests which I kindly ask someone to explain. The correctly marked answer is A, however I don't understand why D isn't the correct one.

Question:

What is the default behavior for instancing service objects in WCF?

A - Each instance is associated with one user-defined service object.

B - Each instance handles all requests for the lifetime of the requesting application.

C - A new instance is created for each client request.

D - A new instance is created for each new client session.

Thakns in advance,
Bruno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer from msdn forums, I guess I'm convinced with it.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/2e35729f-603a-4a52-a3b7-920c9f3a8100/

Quoting the answer:

> This is a tricky one - I assume that the reason D is not true is that
>   not every client creates a session. For example basicHttpBinding does
>   not support sessions. So if you don't always have a session - D is not
>   always true. However, A is always true (unless you create your own
>   custom behavior) because every InstanceContext object wraps a single
>   user-defined service object (an object created according to your
>   service type)

Answer (score 2):

It's PerSession

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx

> If you use the default instancing behavior in WCF, all calls between a WCF client object are handled by the same service instance. Therefore, at the application level, you can think of a session as enabling application behavior similar to local call behavior. For example, when you create a local object:
>   A constructor is called.
>   All subsequent calls made to the WCF client object reference are processed by the same object instance.
>   A destructor is called when the object reference is destroyed.
>   Sessions enable a similar behavior between clients and services as long as the default service instance behavior is used. If a service contract requires or supports sessions, one or more contract operations can be marked as initiating or terminating a session by setting the IsInitiating and IsTerminating properties.

Answer (score 0):

I would think D is correct as well, since `InstanceContextMode` is set to `PerSession` by default ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx)).